# Using enable_if to disable a template constructor of a template class

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates, sfinae

I'm trying to disable a template constructor of a template class using `std::enable_if` when the type of the arguments of the template constructor matches the type "`MyClass`" so that I can use my other constructor which allows me to initialize the class of current template with the class of another one.

```
template <typename t, size_t size>
class MyClass
{
public: 
   MyClass() { data.fill(static_cast<T>(0)); }

   template <typename... Args> // i want to disable this if Args = MyClass
   MyClass(Args&&... args) : data{ std::forward<Args>(args)... } {}

   template <size_t size2>
   MyClass(const Myclass<t, size2>& other_sized_template) { /*do stuff*/ } // this won't work unless the template ctor above is disabled if the arguments passed are of type Myclass

private:
   std::array<t, size> data;
};
```

Comment: sorry... with "i want to disable this if Args = MyClass" do you mean "if all Args are equals to MyClass"? Or "if one of Args is equal to MyClass"? Or what?

Comment: @max66 It's not written in the clearest manner, but the OP wants to disable the variadic constructor if `sizeof...(Args) == 1` **and** `Args[0] "==" MyClass<t, anySize>`. Basically, the OP wants the other constructor to have a higher priority than the variadic one

Comment: @Justin - I see... thanks.

Comment: `MyClass<float, 3> one = {1.f, 3.f, 5.f, } ; // I want to use the 2nd ctor for this` and instead for this  `MyClass<float, 4> two = one; // I want to use the 3rd ctor for this instead of the 2nd one.` I want to achieve this effect by using std::enable_if and probably is_same (or something similar) on 2nd template forwarding ctor.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check whether the type is an instantiation of `MyClass` by a class template with partial specialization. e.g.

```
template<class...>
struct is_MyClass : std::false_type {};

template <typename T, size_t size>
struct is_MyClass<MyClass<T, size>> : std::true_type {};
```

then disable the constructor like

```
template <typename... Args, 
          typename = std::enable_if_t<
            !is_MyClass<
              std::remove_cv_t<
                std::remove_reference_t<Args>>...>::value> > // i want to disable this if Args = MyClass
MyClass(Args&&... args) : data{ std::forward<Args>(args)... } {}
```

[LIVE](https://wandbox.org/permlink/PaXLJNptFFdLEiMQ)

Answer (score 1):

First you need a helper to be able to tell if `Args...` are a single `MyClass<T, N>`:

```
#include <cstddef>
#include <type_traits>

template <class, size_t>
class MyClass;

template <class T>
struct IsMyClass {
    template <size_t Size>
    static std::true_type test(const MyClass<T, Size>&);

    static std::false_type test(...);

    template <class V, class... Further>
    static constexpr bool value = (
        (sizeof...(Further) == 0) &&
        decltype(test(std::declval<V>()))::value
    );
};
```

You can use it like

```
IsMyClass<int>::template value<Args...>
```

to test if `Args...` are `MyClass<int, Some_Int>`. Now use this helper:

```
#include <cstdio>

template <typename T, size_t Size>
class MyClass
{
public: 
    MyClass() {
        printf("Default constructor\n");
    }

    template <
        class ...Args,
        class Check = std::enable_if_t<(!IsMyClass<T>::template value<Args...>)>
    >
    MyClass(Args&&... args) {
        printf("Args != MyClass\n");
    }

    template <size_t Size2>
    MyClass(const MyClass<T, Size2>& other_sized_template) {
        printf("other_sized_template\n");
    }
};
```

A simple test if it works:

```
int main() {
    printf("init\n");
    MyClass<int, 10> myclass_int10;
    MyClass<void, 10> myclass_void10;

    printf("1+2\n");
    MyClass<int, 20> test1(myclass_int10);
    MyClass<int, 20> test2(myclass_void10);

    printf("3+4\n");
    MyClass<void, 20> test3(myclass_int10);
    MyClass<void, 20> test4(myclass_void10);

    printf("5+6\n");
    MyClass<int, 20> test5(myclass_int10, myclass_int10);
    MyClass<int, 20> test6(myclass_void10, myclass_void10);

    return 0;
}
```

And it does:

```
$ g++ -std=c++14 ./x.cpp
$ ./a.out 
init
Default constructor
Default constructor
1+2
other_sized_template
Args != MyClass
3+4
Args != MyClass
other_sized_template
5+6
Args != MyClass
Args != MyClass
```

Comment: Whenever I try to initialize with an initializer_list like so `Myclass<float, 3> test = {1.f, 2.f, 3.f};` it doesn't work.

Comment: @JohnWayne, what does "doesn't work" mean? In my test it calls the `printf("Args != MyClass\n"); ` variant.

Comment: This gives me the error that 'initializing': cannot convert from 'MyClass<float, 3>' to 'float' when I do MyClass<float, 3> test = { 1.f, 2.f, 3.f };

Answer (score 1):

The best I can imagine is define a type traits, say `notOnlyOneMyClass`

```
template <typename ...>
struct notOnlyOneMyClass
 { using type = void; };

template <typename T, std::size_t S>
struct notOnlyOneMyClass<T, MyClass<T, S>>
 { };
```

that receive a list of types and define a `type` ever with the exception of the case when receive only two types and the second one is a `MyClass` with type corresponding to the first one.

Now the use of SFINAE is simple

```
  template <typename... Args,
            typename notOnlyOneMyClass<T,
               typename std::decay<Args>::type...>::type * = nullptr>
  MyClass (Args && ... args) : data{ { std::forward<Args>(args)... } }
   { }
```

The following is a full working example

```
#include <array>

template <typename, std::size_t>
class MyClass;

template <typename ...>
struct notOnlyOneMyClass
 { using type = void; };

template <typename T, std::size_t S>
struct notOnlyOneMyClass<T, MyClass<T, S>>
 { };

template <typename T, std::size_t S>
class MyClass
 {
   public: 
      MyClass()
       { data.fill(static_cast<T>(0)); }

      template <typename... Args,
                typename notOnlyOneMyClass<T,
                   typename std::decay<Args>::type...>::type * = nullptr>
      MyClass (Args && ... args) : data{ { std::forward<Args>(args)... } }
       { }

      template <std::size_t S2>
      MyClass (MyClass<T, S2> const & ost)
       { } 

   private:
      std::array<T, S> data;
 };


int main ()
 {
   MyClass<int, 1U>   mi1;
   MyClass<int, 2U>   mi2{1, 2};
   MyClass<int, 3U>   mi3{mi1};
   MyClass<int, 4U>   mi4{std::move(mi2)};
   MyClass<int, 5U>   mi5{MyClass<int, 6U>{}};
   // MyClass<int, 6U>   mi6{MyClass<long, 7U>{}}; // error! int != long
 }
```